# Iterate over files in GitHub repo from a Jupyter Notebook inside the repo

Tags: python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook

I have this folder in my GitHub repo:

[image]

Inside this repo, I have a Jupyter notebook, and I use [MyBinder](https://mybinder.org/) to render this notebook into a web app. Inside the notebook, I iterate over the files in the `rasters_as_int` folder and extract the date from the file name. All the files have the same name pattern, for example, one of the files is named: `MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2019-06-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF`.

In the previous version of the repo, there was no folder and all these files were on the repo "main page" (sorry if this is not the proper name for it), so in the notebook, I used the `glob` package to iterate over them (and extract the date using Python `split` method):

```
rasters_list = glob.glob('*TIFF*')
```

And it works perfectly.

However, I can't seem to find how to iterate when these files are in the `rasters_as_in` folder.
I tried many options but nothing seems to work:

```
rasters_list = glob.glob('rasters_as_int/*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('/rasters_as_int/*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('./rasters_as_int/*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('rasters_as_int\\*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('\\rasters_as_int\\*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('.\\rasters_as_int\\*TIFF*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('rasters_as_int/*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('/rasters_as_int/*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('./rasters_as_int/*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('.\\rasters_as_int\\*')
rasters_list = glob.glob('/rasters_as_int/*',recursive=True)
```

Comment: The right term for the 'the repo "main page"' you are trying to describe is the root of the repository which corresponds to the root directory of the instance. I believe [this](https://github.com/ran-pelta/CloudTool) is your repository so that I could test my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third option works fine.

I just tested that and a variation at https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ran-pelta/CloudTool/7bd082bb3cf7b2e202dc43841fc60e7796c7402a , which uses the repo before you removed the `rasters_as_int` directory. Example glob that works to give output I show next:

```py
rasters_list = glob.glob('./rasters_as_int/*TIFF')
```

And I get stuff like this (truncated for brevity with `...`) when I put `rasters_list` alone in a subsequent cell:

```py
['./rasters_as_int/MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2020-01-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF',
 './rasters_as_int/MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2019-06-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF',
 './rasters_as_int/MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2020-03-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF',
 './rasters_as_int/MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2020-12-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF', ... 
]
```

(See a picture below of that, too. I added it now for more context since I ended up adding an image showing the plot.)

You probably weren't accounting for the `./rasters_as_int/` part in your split of the file name? Because it looks like you changed it from `date = pd.to_datetime(i.split('_')[4]) # this is if the TIFFs are in current folder` to `date = pd.to_datetime(tail.split('_')[4])`.

And with that glob command the notebook works from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ran-pelta/CloudTool/7bd082bb3cf7b2e202dc43841fc60e7796c7402a) using what is in `rasters_as_int`. I see the dates along the plot.[image]

---

Here's showing what I see from that glob as an image,too, since it shows your other code in context:

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to delete my previous comment... but what I wanted to say was:I did change the extraction of the date to: `head,tail = os.path.split(i)`
`date = pd.to_datetime(tail.split('_')[4])`, where i should be for example: `'./rasters_as_int/MODAL2_M_CLD_FR_2020-01-01_rgb_3600x1800.FLOAT.TIFF'` that suppose to get the date as text and then I convert them to pandas datetime, but for some reason it does not work

Comment: Ok, so your answer helped me to find the right option. The other problem, which I was not aware of was probably due to my repo Python "blocking" the MyBinder Python, or something like that, I opened a new repo without specifying "Python" in the gitignore and now it works fine. Thank you